# Bulk identifying images with FFMPEG that contain a graphic

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, image-manipulation, bulk

I need to be able to bulk sort through images that contain a graphic and remove these images from the folder. The graphic is a ruler-like image for scale.

I'm a novice with FFMPEG, but have already written a batch script that resizes images. The logic seems pretty understandable, however my issue is that I don't know what and where to research for a solution to my problem. From what I read, imagemagik might also be a great tool, but I feel more comfortable with FFMPEG.

I expect the script to look through all image files in a folder and find those the contain the ruler graphic and remove the said images with the rule graphic from the folder. The images are product shots on white backgrounds and the rule graphic is not overlaying anything or acting like a watermark.

Ideally, if possible, a way to crop out the graphics would be an amazing next step.

Comment: Why FFmpeg? Based on your description your approach should be using OpenCV with something like [Template Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/da9/tutorial_template_matching.html).

Comment: It's just my ignorance regarding ffmpeg and other tools out there. I've never heard about OpenCV, this is perfect. Thank you so much for this! However, I don't really have any programming experience. I'll check out some tutorials online, I'm sure it's doable for my (lack of) experience. Would OpenCV be enough for me to complete all the tasks? Or would I need something else as well? Also curious, would it be possible to crop out or delete the said graphic with OpenCV as well? I really appreciate your time and help, Aergistal!

Comment: It's a great opportunity to learn, there are examples for template matching on the linked page. If the size of the ruler varies you also have to progressively scale the image and re-scan it which can result in a lot of processing. Once you get a match with a high enough accuracy you'll have a bounding box which may be used to fill or crop the original image.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate all of your help. Gotta say, I love the internet :)